# How to enforce a date value input in a REST API?

Tags: java, rest

The user needs to make a `POST` to `/api/date` with something like `March 13, 2019` or `08/19/2020`. As long as it's a date, it should be accepted.

I have something like this (Using Dropwizard framework)

```
@POST
public void post(String date)
{
  validateDate(date);
  //continue
}

private void validateDate(String date)
{
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try
    {
        LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
    }
    catch (DateTimeParseException e)
    {
      //not a date
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm in the right approach, there must be a better way to validate strings as dates.

Comment: you are guessing the format (`yyyy-MM-dd"`) while first you need to figure out what the format **is**

Comment: Is it better to only accept one date format? I was hoping to keep it flexible so different formats can be used.

Comment: @RonApple1996 Just use one date format. APIs should be **well-defined** contracts.

Comment: It depends of what you want. `DateTimeFormatter` accepts `[]` as optional format string so you could have something like: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[MM/dd/yyyy][yyyy-MM-dd]")`
But in my opinion, you should stay with one date format to stay consistent with you API contracts.

Comment: @Michael once a date is created, I return the date back in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`. So does it make sense for the user to provide a similar format? (year, month, day, hours, min and seconds). Seems weird to me to allow even seconds, I don't think it needs to go that much into detail

Comment: @RonApple1996 If you need a date, ask for a date. Given you have the control, I would use an [ISO-8601 standard date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) e.g. 2011-12-21

Comment: @RonApple1996 either way, be sure to make it very explicit which timezone you expect, even if it is date-only.

Comment: Yea @Hulk, I was just thinking about that. Ahhh dates have so much involved.. I'm returning UTC time zone, so I think logically it makes sense to accept only UTC time as well

Comment: @RonApple1996, yes, being able to restrict it to UTC definitely simplifies things

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: *It is not really clear if you want to know how to validate dates correctly or how to handle invalid inputs to your REST API. My answer shows the latter.*

You should use a return value for your post method. You can return [javax.ws.rs.core.Response](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html), with that you can control the HTTP code and response object you want to return.

On success, you would normally return the created object with a 200 success code.
On failure, you would return an error code (like 400 Bad request) with a detailed error message ("Date must be in the format yyyy-MM-dd").

To create the response, you can use the ResponseBuilder.

Example:

```
Response.ok( yourObject ).build(); //success
Response.status( Status.BAD_REQUEST ).entity( yourErrorMessageObject ).build(); // failure
```

So I would change the code to this:

```
@POST
public Response post(String date)
{
  if(!isDateValid(date)){
     return Response.status( Status.BAD_REQUEST ).entity( buildErrorMessage()).build();
  }

  //continue
  Response.ok().build(); // returns nothing on success (like void)
}

private boolean isDateValid(String date)
{
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try
    {
        LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
        return true;
    }
    catch (DateTimeParseException e)
    {
      //not a date
      return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accept multiple formats for a date time using the optional syntax `([<your format>])*`. eg

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
    "[yyyy-MM-dd][dd-MM-yyyy][MMMM dd, yyyy]");
```